# Rails find through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one     :address, :foreign_key => "customerid"
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :customer, :foreign_key => "customerid"
end
```

How do I find records in customer that do not have customerid in address table?

in SQL i'd do

```
select * from customer a, address b where a.customerid <> b.customerid
```

Answer (score 0):

This will return `customers` that doesn't have `address`:

```
Customer.find :all, 
   :conditions => 'id NOT IN (select distinct customerid from address)'
```

Hope I understood your question correctly.